# Is there a way to display an image in CkEditor textarea from public folder in Laravel

Tags: html, css, laravel, ckeditor

I have a ckeditor created that works fine, but I want to display a logo(.jpeg) within the text area that will sit at top left corner.

I have done this:

```
<textarea id="forwarding_letter" width='100%' height='100%' name="letter">
<img src="{{url('/img/newlogo.jpeg')}}" alt="" height="180" width="180">
<div style="width:100%; text-align: right"><strong><u>CONFIDENTIAL</u></strong></div> 
</textarea>
```

But image is not displayed.

I have also done this:

```
body{
   background-image: url("../img/editorBackground.png") !important;
   background-repeat: repeat-x;
   background-attachment: local !important;
}
```

This also does not work.

Comment: how do you configure filesystems.php file in laravel

Comment: The `textarea` elemnt is fully replaced with Ckeditor. It's not possible. May be the editor itself offers you this feature.

Answer (score 0):

**Change** `/img/newlogo.jpeg` **to** `img/newlogo.jpeg`

Which produces the following

```
"http://your.url/img/newlogo.jpeg"
```